# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/Manifest$permission;

Tags: android, static-libraries

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/Manifest$permission;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/Manifest$permission;
```

How to solve this problem?

```
When i try to run my project that time Console displays this type of error, How to solved it, please help me if you have any idea regarding to this.
```